# Excel VBA - Save as PDF hangs when run from Windows Task Scheduler

Tags: excel, pdf, scheduled-tasks

I have a VB Script wrapper application, which calls an Excel application to generate a PDF document.

When the script is run as a logged on user there is no problem and I successfully get the PDF document. However, when I setup the script as a Windows Task Scheduler entry, the process run but hangs at the following code:

```
ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat _
                         Type:=xlTypePDF, _
                         Filename:=strOutputPDFFilename, _
                         Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
                         IncludeDocProperties:=False, _
                         IgnorePrintAreas:=True, _
                         OpenAfterPublish:=False
```

I have put debug around this and this is definitely the point where the process fails to complete. I have additionally added the Windows Task Scheduler account to the administrators group but with no affect.

Comment: Do you execute this with a `.bat` file calling the Excel File? Or how? I have several methods like this one you have implanted at my office and they cause this problem, and my codes are pretty much like yours.

Comment: Sorry, I meaned *They do not cause this problem* on my previous comment

Comment: How is strOutputPDFFilename built?

Comment: The Excel application is called via a VB Script application and I have used this method for other Excel applications. The issue I'm facing on this occasion is the production of the PDF. The strOutputPDFFilename contains the path and filename of the output document i.e. C:\Temp\Filename.pdf and as I mentioned, when I run the VB script as a signed on user, the process works as expected.

Comment: To add... the Excel application does not progress past the code above but just hangs there and no error is generated.

Comment: *when I run the VB script as a signed on user*. You mean you are logged in? And in task scheduler you are not logged in?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: I've also checked the Process ID of the Excel application and while it is in this state, the CPU is 0% and the memory is the fixed.

Comment: I replaced the xlTypePDF with xlTypeXPS but again no document. As before, when I run the process as a signed on user, the document for both types are generated.

Comment: Have you tried being logged in when task scheduler executes?

Comment: Whilst logged on, I manually Started the process in Windows Task Scheduler and again nothing happens. I created a desktop shortcut replicating the arguments from the Scheduler and the process is now generating the PDF documents as expected. It appears all the components required to create the PDF files are found but there's something about running the process from within the Scheduler, which is affecting the process.

Comment: *and again nothing happens* No error like the one you posted in the question?

Comment: No error is triggered. The process just hangs at the code above (.ExportAsFixedFormat). I've even split the (.Close SaveChanges:=False) but the process never gets to this.

Comment: I should also mention the process is setup in Task Scheduler on the server running Windows Server 2012 R2. I don't know if there's some security setting for Office which is preventing the export of the PDF.

Comment: Completed further testing and identified the process hangs only when the Task Schedule element [Run whether user is logged on or not] is selected. I've checked the user is in the Administrators group.

Comment: Out of curiosity I changed the Task Schedule setting for [When running the task, use the following user account:] to a different Administrator account and the process now works. Not sure what to check now as the previous AD user was already in the Administrators group.